Выполнить действие по кнопке
как сделать так, что бы действия были после нажатия на кнопку?
нужно сделать так, чтобы по кнопке воспроизводилось видео, но окно с кнопкой и видео начинают выполняться одновременно. не понимаю в чем проблема. пробовал гуглить варианты решения, но ничего не нвшел
вот код 

Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Отступы в python имеют значение. Чтобы действие выполнялось после нажатия на кнопку, оно должно быть внутри обработчика нажатия. У вас строка с запуском видео снаружи обработчика нажатия, поэтому выполняется сразу при старте программы, а не после нажатия.

В Python в функцию попадет блок кода, который выделен табуляцией:
def open_video():
    import os

Вы должны поставить перед os.system() табуляцию:
def open_video():
    import os
    os.system(path)

Также, import os в функции писать не нужно, так как вы загрузили модуль в начале кода.
